# Problem in understanding part of a linear algebra lemma.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm having problem in understand the proof of lemma 3.2 on the page 64 of the book Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations (Haim Brezis, first edition).

I have a vector space $X$ and $\phi,\phi_1,\ldots, \phi_k$ are $(k+1)$ linear functionals on $X$. What i want to prove is that if $$\cap_{i=1}^{k}\ker{\phi_i}\subset \ker \phi $$
then $\phi$ is linear combination of $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_k$.

The book does the following: Consider the linear map $F:X \to \mathbb R^{k+1}$ given by $$F(x) = (\phi(x),\phi_1(x),\ldots,\phi_k(x)).$$

Since $a=(1,0,...,0)$ does not belong to $F(X)$ and $F(X)$ is convex there is a hyperplane separating $a$ and $F(X)$. So there exist  $\lambda,\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_k \in \mathbb R$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb R$ such that $$F(a)=\lambda <\alpha < \lambda \phi(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i \phi_i(x)$$
for every $x \in X$.
Then he just says that
\begin{equation}
\lambda \phi(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i \phi_i(x)=0
\end{equation}
for every $x\in X$.

Why does the equality

$$\lambda \phi(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i \phi_i(x)=0,\forall x\in X$$
holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the linear combination is nonzero. By multiplying $x$ by an arbitrary $c\in \mathbb R$ you can make the linear combination to be anything you want, in particular, make it less than $\lambda$.